# Does double quote makes any difference in setenv command in Linux csh?

Tags: linux, unix, csh, setenv

I am setting an environment variable - say ABC -  in C shell in SuSe Linux.

My question, are there any difference in following 2 commands?

1. `$setenv ABC "1"`
2. `$setenv ABC 1`

In both the cases `echo` gave me the same result.

i.e

```
$echo $ABC 
1
```

For me, it looks to be both are same. But I wanted a confirmation to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there are no differences for your example. But `csh` is rightly [considered harmful](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/shell/csh-whynot/), so forget about it. Use `bash` or `zsh` instead.

<sup>My personal preference is to use Posix `/bin/sh` or else `/bin/bash` for scripts, and `zsh` as my interactive login shell</sup>

Comment: Thanks for that info. I will be in transition state from right now ;-)

Answer (score 1):

In a nutshell if the value assigned to your environment variable include spaces you will need to use quotes.

Here's a [link](http://sc.tamu.edu/help/general/unix/vars.html) with more information about shell and environment variables.  Search for the setenv on the page.

Comment: If the value of the environment variables has spaces you'll need quotes (even if the name of the variables don't have spaces).

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Thanks for catching that.  That's what I intended to say.  Post corrected.